# How to get eBay feedbacks from URL using Python, BeautifulSoup, re

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

Does someone knows how to get ebay feedbacks from site using python3, beautifulsoup, re...

I have this code but it is not easy to find feedbacks.

```
import urllib.request 
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('http://feedback.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewFeedback2&userid=nana90store&iid=-1&de=off&items=25&searchInterval=30&which=positive&interval=30&_trkparms=positive_30')

for line in fhand:
    print (line.strip())
    f=open('feedbacks1.txt','a')
    f.write(str(line)+'\n')
    f.close()


file = open('feedbacks1.txt', 'r')
cleaned = open('cleaned.txt', 'w')
soup = BeautifulSoup(file)
page = soup.getText()
letters_only = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", page )
cleaned.write(str(letters_only))
```

Comment: Your code just gets each line of the HTML file, but you need to access the actual data contained on the page. BeautifulSoup can reference DIVs and table cells etc directly - just look at the source code of the ebay page, identify the structure of the feedback, then code you version accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just care for the feedback text this might be what you are looking for:

```
import urllib.request 
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

fhand = urllib.request.urlopen('http://feedback.ebay.com/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewFeedback2&userid=nana90store&iid=-1&de=off&items=25&searchInterval=30&which=positive&interval=30&_trkparms=positive_30')
soup = BeautifulSoup(fhand.read(), 'html.parser')
table = soup.find(attrs = {'class' : 'FbOuterYukon'})
for tr in table.findAll('tr'):
    if not tr.get('class'):
        print(list(tr.children)[1].getText())
```

I am first finding the table with feedback, then the rows that contain the feedback (no class) and then the relevant lines and parse the corresponding text. This can also be adapted for similar needs.